# Converting 64-bit ROP gadget memory addresses into working shellcode

Tags: c, shellcode

How does this process work exactly? What I mean more specifically is that I want to gdb into the program, run it, find a memory address to convert into working shellcode. What commands would I need to input into the program? I would like to convert a 64-bit memory address into functioning shellcode. This is on a Linux machine.  I wanted to do some generalized stack reading and logically work my way up the stack using different algorithms.

Also, ROP gadget tools give memory addresses when generating a ROP chain. I'd like to incorporate shellcode into the mix as well as possibly convert the ROP memory addresses directly to simplified shellcode. Would this be feasible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A 64 bit address is just 64 bits of data that are interpreted as an address. Shellcode, in this context, is a variable-length set of instructions. What do you think "converting" would do?

Comment: To be able to use as shell code on an executable stack or an R/X region of memory? How do I convert 0x4001edfffffa for example to shell code? Do I need to gdb in and retrieve x/8x for that memory address and organize it accordingly due to little/big endian?

Comment: Sorry, that does not make any sense to me. I suspect you have a fundamental misunderstanding how shellcode works, and not enough familiarity with assembly and CPU's. I don't see how this question can be salvaged.